# botkit-sms: Integrating middleware plugin

Tags: node.js, botkit

I'm trying to api.ai middleware plugin with botkit-sms, I'm tryting to debug the source code, why this isn't working, but will be helpful if you can provide some input

Source code of the library https://github.com/krismuniz/botkit-sms/

```
var apiai = require('botkit-middleware-apiai')({
  token: '...',
  skip_bot: true // or false. If true, the middleware don't send the bot reply/says to api.ai
})

controller.middleware.receive.use(apiai.receive)

controller.hears('.*', 'message_received', apiai.hears, function (bot, message) {
  console.log('received :: ' + message)
  bot.reply(message, 'got the message')
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `apiai.hears` into the hears function here changes how pattern matching and hears works. You are now matching intents instead of user using regex on user input.

But the issue is that [API.ai middleware uses an `===` operator](https://github.com/abeai/botkit-middleware-apiai/blob/master/src/botkit-middleware-apiai.js#L56) when matching, not regex. So the pattern `.*` won't match anything unless you have an intent named that.